# WCF Rest with combined authentication modes

Tags: wcf, rest, authentication

I have created a self-hosted WCF RESTful service with basic http authentication that runs over https with a self-signed SSL certificate. Everything works fine. Users access the service operations via a web browser.

The problem is that my customer now wants the service users to authenticate with **BOTH** basic authentication (user name + password) AND a certificate. I have not been able to achieve this.

I have seen that it could be possible to have multiple authentication schemes in WCF 4.5. I have looked into this but to no avail.

I have also come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806067/which-security-mode-to-use-in-wcf-client-with-ssl-and-http-authentication) (see the last answer), but when I tried it I got this error:

"An exception occurred: HTTPS listener factory was configured to require a client certificate and the authentication scheme 'Basic'. Only one form of authentication can be required at once."

My configuration is done in code, and here is what it looks like (this is the version that works):

```
Uri baseAdress = new Uri("https://localhost:8446/"); 
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(RestService));
WebHttpBinding wb = new WebHttpBinding();
wb.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
wb.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRestService), wb, baseAdress);
host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNameValidator();
host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { HelpEnabled = true });
host.Open();
```

Thanks for any tips,

Answer (score 0):

Multi auth on a single endpoint is for web hosted scenarios (not selfhost). You can configure this in web host by saying clientCredentialType='InheritFromHost' and set all the auth schemes that you want to set for that particular endpoint in vdir authentication. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx) documentation for title "Multiple authentication support".

> > Multiple Authentication Support
> >     Support has been added to support multiple authentication modes, as supported by IIS, on a single WCF endpoint when using the HTTP transport and transport security. IIS allows you to enable multiple authentication modes on a virtual directory, this feature allows a single WCF endpoint to support the multiple authentication modes enabled for the virtual directory where the WCF service is hosted.

Comment: I am afraid IIS is not an option for me. I have seen from the link you posted that it is supposed to be possible with self hosted services as well. But from all authentication modes available, I don't see anything  with certificates :(